# How to retrieve 'Outer tag' attribute selection in XQuery?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery, xslt-2.0

I have  simple following xml

```
<refData xmlns="">
<type name="listed">
    <typeID>LISTED_BUILDING</typeID>
</type>
<type name="cust_title">
    <typeID>TITLE</typeID>
</type>
</refData>
```

Using the 'typeID' tag how do  I retrieve 'type' name attribute ? What would be the xQuery for this ?  In another word , how do I retrieve 'type' name attribute  which matches to a typeID ?

Comment: Have you checked any XPath tutorial and simple path expressions? Even the spec has examples https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev that should allow you to get started.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get all the attribute string values of the `type` with the `typeID` "TITLE" is the following:

```
let $file := doc("input.xml")/refData return
for $type in $file/type[typeID='TITLE']
return string($type/@name)
```

Output here is

> cust_title

Except for using the `string()` function to handle the output of the attribute this is ansolute basic stuff explained in every XQuery tutorial at the beginning. You can, for example, start at [W3Schools XQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_intro.asp), but there are tons of other tutorials, some of them probably better. But it seems that you should consider reading an [XPath tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response , but I was looking for one XPath expression , instead of multiple step as I need to specify in synapse configuration. Synapse accept one XPath expression only , something like .. type[typeID='TITLE'] /@name, But it’s throwing  some exception.

Comment: @BrijeshNK : could you please share the exception you are getting? so that people can help you on the exact issue. thanks.

Comment: You can compress it to one line: `let $attr := string(doc("input.xml")/refData/type[typeID='TITLE']/@name) return $attr`. In case of your example the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You tagged your story with many related (but not the same) tags.  You referenced xQuery in the title of the story. The answer from zx485 is a perfectly valid xQuery response.

I noted, however, contrary to the title, you left a note explaining that you wanted a pure xPath example.  Please see an xPath example below:

```
xquery version "1.0";

<refData xmlns="">
  <type name="listed">
    <typeID>LISTED_BUILDING</typeID>
  </type>
  <type name="cust_title">
    <typeID>TITLE</typeID>
  </type>
</refData>/type[./typeID/text() = "TITLE"]/@name
```

Returns: `cust_title`

The actual xPath I chose was `/type[./typeID/text() = "TITLE"]/@name`

- Iterate over the type elements
- Select the ones that match on the text of the child element called typeID
- For those selected, xPath into the attribute

Comment: `/type[./typeID/text() = "TITLE"]/@name` cannot work here because `type` is not the root element.

Comment: My sample works just fine... The person posting said that they had simple xnl as in the sample. Copy and paste my sample as an xml fragment and it works fine. If the example needs to be for a document node (never made clear) then starting with /refData/type or double slash //type (if you know and trust the structure) will work in those cases.